# Set histogram of size surf descriptors

Tags: histogram, sift, surf, motion

I'm trying to compute a motion histogram of the region around surf descriptor, and i don't know if there is a method to compute the size of the histogram (how many bins) and the size of the patch (the region of the neighborhood around the interest point)?
Is there any relation between the surf scale and the histogram?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Size(number of bins) of the motion histogram is always the same - number of the directions you divide motion. You specify it.

Scale is one of the parameters of the detected SURF keypoint, you can simply access it. About relation -it is the same question as  "is there any relation between size of the patch and its movement?". Depends on your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer:) I have two directions of the optical flow, every direction is described by an angle. In sift for example, they use 4*4 patches every patch is described by an histogram of 8 bins. In my case i don't know how to chose how many bins (angles). Thanks again

Comment: The best would be to try different numbers and check which works better.